# Not clear how to inject custom ObjectMapper for @SpringBootTest(SomeController.class)

Tags: java, junit, spring-boot-test, objectmapper, mockmvc

Affects: \3.1.5

I am using custom configuration for an ObjectMapper like that:

```
@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@Override
public void extendMessageConverters (List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.stream()
            .filter(x -> x instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter)
            .forEach(x -> ((MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) x).setObjectMapper(objectMapper));
}
```

It is working OK in app, but I can't inject the same configuration to my JUnits. Is @SpringBootTest(Controller.class) possible to inject custom ObjectMapper or extendMessageConverter?

I tried injecting the previous JsonConfiguration and doing the following, but it did not work:

```
mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).setControllerAdvice(jsonConfiguration).build();
```

Please provide more details or workaround.
Thanks!

Comment: Consider using constructor injection instead of Autowired - this makes it easy to set up tests, and avoids the need to use SprintBootTest.

Comment: Please share your entire test code. Are you using `@SpringBootTest` or `@WebMvcTest`?